# Dados nao aparecem no datagridview, mesmo setando um datasource populado, Por que?

Tags: winforms, vb.net, datagridview

Estou tentando capturar algumas informações do banco, filtra-las e em seguida fazer testes de validação em cada uma das linhas retornadas. Depois, eu tento pegar as linhas que falharam no teste e inserir num novo datatable. Entretanto, depois de ter o datatable preenchido e te-lo associado ao datagridview como um datasource, os dados nao aparecem no objeto datagridview.

O que pode ser?

```
    Dim Aviso As New frmWarning
    Dim Filtros As String
    Dim DtTable As New DataTable
    Dim DtView As DataView

    Aviso.Abrir()

    Filtros = "Data >= '" & DtInicial.Text & "'"
    Filtros = Filtros & " and Data <= '" & DtFinal.Text & "'"
    Filtros = Filtros & " and Loja = " & Me.cmbLojas.SelectedValue

    With dgvCPF
        .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
        .DataSource = Nothing
        .ColumnCount = 7
        .Columns(0).Name = "TipoDaNota"
        .Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "TipoDaNota"
        .Columns(1).Name = "CPF_CNPJ"
        .Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "CPF_CNPJ"
    End With


    If NotasTable.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        DtTable = preencheNotasImp() 'Retorna Busca de Dados
        DtView = New DataView(DtTable)
        DtView.RowFilter = Filtros ' Filtra os dados

        Dim CGC As String
        Dim DtAux As New DataTable
        DtTable = DtView.ToTable 'Retorna os dados filtrados para a antiga datatable

        For Each Row As DataRow In DtTable.Rows
            CGC = Row.Item(9).ToString()

            If ValidaCGCCPF.Validations.isCNPJ(CGC) = True Or _
                ValidaCGCCPF.Validations.isCPF(CGC) = True Then

                DtAux.ImportRow(Row) 'Importa linha 

            End If
        Next Row

        dgvCPF.DataSource = DtAux


    End If



    Aviso.Fechar()
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente chamar o DataBind do grid após setar a DataTable:

```
dgvCPF.DataSource = DtAux
dgvCPF.DataBind()
```